# How software update works in VLC media player

Tags: vlc

I am interested to know the what are the major steps involving in the software update process in VLC player. Also I'm interested to know, whether it will be done through the HTTP or FTP server.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I tried software update in My vlc but it downloaded the entire installer package and the installed like a new software. Whereas in Google chrome it works as you said.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Anyhow i just wanted to know, ie. what is the source of the update package whether it is HTTP server or FTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VLC player's updating steps are as follows.

1. VLC player or any applications sends HTTP "POST" to the server which replies 
   the URL of the update file if the update present.
2. Then VLC player downloads the update file using HTTP "GET" method.
3. This process also includes the check sum verification of the file.